# How to compare Date and Boolean at same time in same compare and put with true booleans down and false upper in Android?

Tags: android, sorting, arraylist

I am creating event App, which lists all events.

I have a problem, that when event is over, it still stays up because it was sorted by time if next event is after a week. Like this:
[image]

So, the event which was end, is need to go down and also be sorted by date.

How can I do this?

I tried to sort seperately by date and boolean, but it failed.
Or does I need to create two arraylists for ended events and upcoming?

If someone knows how to do this, please tell me, you save my day.

My code, which sorts right now:

```
Collections.sort(eventsList, new Comparator<TimetableEvent>() {

                @Override
                public int compare(TimetableEvent arg0, TimetableEvent arg1) {
                    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(
                            "dd.MM.yyyy' klo 'HH.mm");
                    int compareResult = 0;
                    try {
                        Date arg0Date = format.parse(arg0.getDateTime());
                        Date arg1Date = format.parse(arg1.getDateTime());

                        compareResult = arg0Date.compareTo(arg1Date);




                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        compareResult = arg0.getDateTime().compareTo(arg1.getDateTime());
                    }
                    return compareResult;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply adapt your `compare()` method so that, if an event is over and the other one is not, it returns without comparing date:

```
@Override
public int compare(TimetableEvent arg0, TimetableEvent arg1) {
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "dd.MM.yyyy' klo 'HH.mm");
    int compareResult = 0;

    if (arg0.isOver() && !arg1.isOver()) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (!arg0.isOver() && arg1.isOver()) {
        return -1;
    }

    try {
        Date arg0Date = format.parse(arg0.getDateTime());
        Date arg1Date = format.parse(arg1.getDateTime());

        compareResult = arg0Date.compareTo(arg1Date);




    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        compareResult = arg0.getDateTime().compareTo(arg1.getDateTime());
    }
    return compareResult;
}
```